# Site icons misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

On both the full site and mobile theme, when viewed from Android and Chrome,  the site icons are misaligned as seen below on the drop down site list. Can't replicate on my mac.

[image]

But new reports are saying this is affecting multiple systems, mobile and desktop: [HNQ site icons are borked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270004/hnq-site-icons-are-borked)

Both the Site Drop Down and the HNQ use the same image and css, so it's all connected.

Comment: I just noticed the same with Safari and Chrome on Mac OS X.

Comment: @MartinR I can't replicate it on Safari 9.0.1 (Yosemite 10.10.5), even if I reload ignoring cache, or change the user agent to Chrome (29)

Comment: I can replicate it with Safari (and Chrome) on OS X 10.10.5, and with Safari on OS X 10.11.1.

Comment: I'm sure this has *nothing* to do with CodeReview's new design going live. It must have been unicorns.

Comment: I am not a CSS expert at all, but it seems that special icons are loaded under the condition "min-device-pixel:1.5". This *could* indicate that the problem occurs on devices with a Retina display.

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4599/132

Comment: @victorstafusa nao. This bug was fixed, and only affected the site icons. It's related as the reason is that they are working on code, but not related as its two separate things. Does that only affect SO.pt meta or all sites?

Comment: @cde Didn't saw that in any other site. However I did not search'd for it exaustively.

Comment: Then the SO.pt mods should escalate on their end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We accidentally icons in wrong size for a while there.

Should be fixed now, sorry!

Comment: `We accidentally icons` HA!

Comment: Confirmed now fixed on my Android phone.

Comment: @cde [it's a meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally)

Comment: @gnat yes, I know. I accidentally a coke bottle too.

Comment: Confirmed on MacBook Pro (Retina).