# HNQ site icons are borked

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hot-questions

[image: HNQ screenshot]

The icons look squished and cropped wrong. I've repro'd this on several sites.

Comment: @cde It's probably the same underlying mechanism, but this question is about HNQ on a desktop computer, while yours is about the site dropdown on a mobile device.

Comment: I'm not seeing this.

Comment: neither am I, running chrome 46.0.2490.86 m on a windows 10 machine is clean

Comment: @Hosch I think this only happens on retina screens.

Comment: We're investigating.