# Icons on Area51 are broken

Tags: bug, design, area-51, icons

Icons on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) are broken.

> [image: a51]

Affect site list, inbox and achievements.

Comment: coulda sworn I have seen this before - not a dupe dupe but https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270001/site-icons-misaligned is related?

Comment: Looks fine now... try clearing cache. If no luck, it means you're being served a corrupted file from SE CDN, think it's hosted by Varnish, and need to be manually kicked to fix those issues.